# HttpInputMessage empty in Spring AbstractHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created a HttpMessageConverter but in its read method the HttpInputMessage is empty, HttpInputMessage.getBody().available() returns 0, but HttpInputMessage.getHeaders().getContentLength() returns the correct content length, also I can see the request body sent in the Chrome console.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of `InputStream.available()` always returns 0. Since there is no guarantee as to the type of inputStream that you will receive trust in the http header content length instead